# Create XML file from existing string

Tags: php, xml

I would like to create a **xml file** from existing string generated in the javascript, and send through post in textarea.

*My code:*

```
<script>

// i load existing xml
var xml=loadXMLDoc("test.xml");

// modding the content
var remove = xml.querySelectorAll("taxfree");
Array.prototype.map.call(remove, function(element){
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);
});

// output xml string to textarea and post it through form
document.getElementById("output").value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml.documentElement);

</script>

<form...>
<textarea id="output" name="output"></textarea>
</form>

...

<?php

if isset($newXML = $_POST["output"]){

// ? generate xml file / what do i do here?

}

?>
```

**EDIT:** MY question is, like the title says, how to output **xml file** from existing string (in my case stored in post variable). (Suggest function / class / custom code etc. that serves for xml file creation and saving it).

Comment: Explain negative vote?

Comment: Probably because you didn't actually ask a question. What part are you having trouble with? How is your code not working?

Comment: @Chris Edited my question, explained it a little bit more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write into a file, try fwrite

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Your xml content');
fclose($fp);
```

PHP doc here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php